# Python Yield prevents output/execution in Scrapy Web Spider Crawler

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, yield

I have an issue with my scrapy spider.  Ipass a response object from one parse function to another. The code will only execute for functions that that do not have a yield request (see difference between the two snippets) Why is this?

```
# Yield in parse_page2 scope; "Parsing page 2" doesn't print
import scrapy


class GetInfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "get_inf"
    # allowed_domains = ["example.com
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.apple.com", callback=self.parse_page1)


    def parse_page1(self, response):
        print"Parsepage1"
        self.printString('This prints yet self.parse_page2(response) does not print if yield is in scope !!!')
        self.parse_page2(response)


    def printString(self, string):
        print string


    def parse_page2(self, response):
        print "Parsing page 2"

        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.google.com", callback=self.parse_page3) 

    def parse_page3(self, response):
        pass
```

output :

```
Parsiing page1
This prints yet self.parse_page2(response) does not print if yield is in its scope !!!
```

As opposed to:

```
# Yield commented out; "Parsing page 2" does print
import scrapy


class GetInfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "get_inf"
    # allowed_domains = ["example.com
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.apple.com", callback=self.parse_page1)


    def parse_page1(self, response):
        print"Parsiing page1"
        self.printString('This prints yet self.parse_page2(response) does not print if yield is in its scope !!!', response )
        self.parse_page2(response)


    def printString(self, string, response):
        print string


    def parse_page2(self, response):
        print "Parsing page 2"

        #yield scrapy.Request("http://www.google.com", callback=self.parse_page3) 

    def parse_page3(self, response):
        pass
```

output:

```
Parsiing page1
This prints yet self.parse_page2(response) does not print if yield is in its scope !!!
Parsing page 2
```

Comment: I discovered that if you have return instead of pass, it works.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using yield?  You are never letting it actually yield a value.  while trying to compute the first value to yield, you hit a second yield.

Comment: This code is just an example for the question. But the same problem is in my actual code. I had already used yield to get a response from a url and wanted to pass it to a different parser without having to revisit the page (saves bandwitdh). But it wouldn't parse it if yield was present in the function as demonstrated above. I don't know much about yield vs return but all the scrapy examples use yield  with items, so that's what I use.

Answer (score 2):

[Scrapy spider callbacks](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders) are expected:

- to return an item, a dict or a Request
- or be iterables of items, dicts or Requests,

> In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return either dicts with extracted data, Item objects, Request objects, or an iterable of these objects.

The 2 most common cases for having iterable callbacks results are:

- either generators using `yield`, generating items, dicts, or Requests
- or returning Python list (`[]`) of items, dicts or Requests

(other Python objects can be iterables too, but let's focus on these 2 cases)

Using `yield` in your callback methods, you're defining [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

> Generators functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop.

So, in your `parse_page1`, if you want to use "results" from another callback method that is using `yield`, you need to iterate on it, capture those generated values, and either:

- `yield` each value again to scrapy engine (making `parse_page1` a generator too)
- or return all values in `parse_page1` as a list

Here's an example spider (say, `spider.py`) with a generator callback, `parse`, using 3 other generator callbacks and 1 callback using return:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse_a, parse_b and parse_c are generators,
        # so we "for loop" over them
        for rb in self.parse_a(response):
            yield rb

        for rb in self.parse_b(response):
            yield rb

        for rb in self.parse_c(response):
            yield rb

        # parse_d returns a single value
        # so we yield it's result directly
        yield self.parse_d(response)

    def parse_a(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_a'")
        yield {"value": "a"}

    def parse_b(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_b'")
        yield {"value": "b"}

    def parse_c(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_c'")
        yield {"value": "c"}

    def parse_d(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_d'")
        return {"value": "d"}
```

`scrapy run spider.py` produces this:

```
$ scrapy runspider spider.py 
2016-06-09 10:40:35 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-06-09 10:40:35 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-09 10:40:35 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com> (referer: None)
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_a'
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'a'}
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_b'
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'b'}
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_c'
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'c'}
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_d'
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'd'}
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 213,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 957,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 9, 8, 40, 36, 144795),
 'item_scraped_count': 4,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 9, 8, 40, 35, 733023)}
2016-06-09 10:40:36 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Now, using a callback method using return for values from generators and non-generator callbacks:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        results = []

        # extend() will loop on the values from the generators,
        # adding them to the list
        results.extend(self.parse_a(response))
        results.extend(self.parse_b(response))
        results.extend(self.parse_b(response))

        # parse_d() returns only 1 value, so we just append the return value
        results.append(self.parse_d(response))

        return results

    def parse_a(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_a'")
        yield {"value": "a"}

    def parse_b(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_b'")
        yield {"value": "b"}

    def parse_c(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_c'")
        yield {"value": "c"}

    def parse_d(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_d'")
        return {"value": "d"}
```

It produces this:

```
$ scrapy runspider spider.py 
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com> (referer: None)
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_a'
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_b'
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_b'
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [test] INFO: I am in 'parse_d'
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'a'}
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'b'}
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'b'}
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com>
{'value': 'd'}
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 213,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 957,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 9, 8, 50, 41, 619777),
 'item_scraped_count': 4,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 9, 8, 50, 41, 225264)}
2016-06-09 10:50:41 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Notice the difference in INFO logs: in the 2nd case, all INFO lines are printed at once, because `parse` consumes all generators before handing results back to scrapy engine, and then scrapy prints the items it got (as a list).

Whereas in the first case, using `parse` as generator, scrapy iterates over the callback results, and sub-callbacks are called one at a time, items being produced on each iteration at `yield` points.

Another variation is to consume sub-callbacks into a list (like in the 2nd example above), and still have `parse` as a generator, but that would less coherent (although still working):

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        results = []

        # extend() will loop on the values from the generators,
        # adding them to the list
        results.extend(self.parse_a(response))
        results.extend(self.parse_b(response))
        results.extend(self.parse_b(response))

        # parse_d() returns only 1 value, so we just append the return value
        results.append(self.parse_d(response))

        for rv in results:
            yield rv

    def parse_a(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_a'")
        yield {"value": "a"}

    def parse_b(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_b'")
        yield {"value": "b"}

    def parse_c(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_c'")
        yield {"value": "c"}

    def parse_d(self, response):
        self.logger.info("I am in 'parse_d'")
        return {"value": "d"}
```